# REST API couldn't create list field

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, spfield, list-column, create-fields

I am trying to create list fields using REST api. But when I call the code given below many times, it creates some of the fields and not all of them.

code:

```
function addnewfield(name){
  $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Flight')/fields",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldText' }, 'Title':''+name+'', 'FieldTypeKind': 2,"StaticName": ""+name+"" }),

        headers: {

             "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "odata-version": "3.0"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log("done");
            //console.log(data)
            console.log("added: " + name);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which sharepoint version are you using?

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `data` property. Try using below code:

```
body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 2, 'Title':'" + fieldName + "'}"
```

However you can also use JSOM to create multiple fields in a list.

**Sources**:

1. [Add a Field in the List in SharePoint 2013 Online Using REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/add-a-field-in-the-list-in-sharepoint-2013-online-using-rest/).
2. [Add Fields to SharePoint 2013 List Using JSOM](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/561309/AddplusFieldsplustoplusSharePointplus-plusListp).

Comment: i'm trying to add 5 field the code only creates 3 of them and in another time it creates only 2

Comment: Have you considered using JSOM to create multiple fields at a time?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Try 2nd link given in above answer.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: yes it works with JSOM